# DMTCP ARMv6 port

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi, porting

I saw on the official DMTCP Website that it can be used on Arm-Arch.
But I do not find any info how to port it to armv6l (actually Raspberry Pi).

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.2.0-4-rpi #1 Debian 3.2.51-1+rpi1 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of DMTCP doesn't support RPi. In future it may support depending upon the user requirements. If you have a use case which would require DMTCP support for RPi, you should write to dmtcp-forum mailing list on source forge (more details here: http://dmtcp.sourceforge.net/contactUs.html) and we will be happy to work on it.

EDIT: The latest DMTCP release (2.3.1) has added support for RPi.